# Specifying sheet to freeze panein excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to freeze panes using code in excel. i have seen several examples on how to do it with the activewindow, im trying to

sepcify it from a button on a different sheet.

I have 2 sheets, "Time" and "Time_and_Cost", i have a button on the "Time" sheet which i want to freeze the top row of

"Time_and_cost".

I have this code currently for freezing panes of the active window.

```
Rows("1:1").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

However, how can i adapt this to specify the worksheet, i assume i have to select the worksheet to freeze, freeze it, then

select previous worksheet? im having trouble find the exact code to use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Public Sub FreezePane()
 Dim shName As String
 shName = ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Time_and_Cost").Activate
 Range("A2").Activate
 ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shName).Activate
End Sub
```

Note that I'm activating A2 on  "Time_and_Cost" prior to freezing the panes so that the top row will be frozen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below.

```
Sub FreezePanes()
Worksheets("Time_And_Cost").Activate
Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```